# Dynamic / Changing variable in AJAX get Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I have a page on a project I'm developing that is attempting to make an ajax request with a specific value assigned by the button's (there are multiple) id tag. This works; the value is successfully passed and an ajax call is triggered on every click.

When I try to make the call again to the same page with a different button the variables are reassigned however the **GET request that is sent remains unchanged**.

How do I pass a NEW variable (in this case id) passed into the GET request?

```
function someAJAX(target) {

    var trigger = [target.attr('id')];
    console.log[trigger];

    $.ajax({
        // The URL for the request
        url: "onyxiaMenus/menuBase.php",

        // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
        data: {
            //class: target.attr("class"),
            tableCall: true,
            sort: trigger,
            sortOrder: 'DESC',
        },

        // Whether this is a POST or GET request
        type: "GET",

        // The type of data we expect back
        //The available data types are text, html, xml, json, jsonp, and script.
        dataType: "html",

        // Code to run if the request succeeds;
        // the response is passed to the function
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("AJAX success!");
            $('#prop').replaceWith(data);

        }
        ,

        // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
        // status codes are passed to the function
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Sorry, there was a problem!");
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            console.dir(xhr);
        }
        ,

        // Code to run regardless of success or failure
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            console.log("The request is complete!");
            $('#view').prepend(xhr);

        }


    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".sort").on( "click", function (e) {
        //e.stopPropagation();
        //e.preventDefault();

        target = $(this);
        //console.log(target.attr("class"));
        console.log(target.attr("id"));


        /* ADD CHILDREN TO ELEMENT*/
        if (target.hasClass('asc')) {
            target.removeClass('asc')
        } else {
            target.addClass('asc')
        }

        /* MANAGE CLASS ADD/REMOVE FOR TARGET AND SIBLINGS */
        if (target.hasClass('btn-primary')) {
        } else {
            target.addClass('btn-primary')
        }

        someAJAX(target);

        target.siblings().removeClass('btn-primary');


    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call your ajax like this `someAJAX.bind(target)();` 
Then in function become

```
function someAJAX() {

$.ajax({
    // The URL for the request
    url: "onyxiaMenus/menuBase.php",

    // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
    data: {
        //class: this.attr("class"),
        tableCall: true,
        sort: this.attr('id'),
        sortOrder: 'DESC',
    },

    // Whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "GET",

    // The type of data we expect back
    //The available data types are text, html, xml, json, jsonp, and script.
    dataType: "html",

    // Code to run if the request succeeds;
    // the response is passed to the function
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("AJAX success!");
        $('#prop').replaceWith(data);

    }
    ,

    // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
    // status codes are passed to the function
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Sorry, there was a problem!");
        console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        console.log("Status: " + status);
        console.dir(xhr);
    }
    ,

    // Code to run regardless of success or failure
    complete: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log("The request is complete!");
        $('#view').prepend(xhr);

    }


});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`trigger` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. That's the only data that would be changing between your requests as the other ones are statically coded.

You just need to make sure `trigger` is defined and changes between the two requests.

Comment: Trigger is defined in the second line in the ajax function. The actual calls are working but only the first call.

Comment: ah i missed that.. what exactly do you mean it's not working the second time. what is it doing? are you getting your errors in the console? also, is the target the same element both times the function is called, cus if it is it's just going to be the same exact call.. that would explain why nothing seems to be happening..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input on this problem. I got down to the bottom of my problem. My requests were being handled correctly but dumping the tables was creating syntax errors preventing the appending of new information to my page.

Thanks for the quick replies!
It wall works now.